# How to synchronize a Producer thread and a Consumer thread [C++/CLI]

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c++-cli

*EDIT*: Forget to say the program has to be in .NET 3.5; Visual Studio 2008 and Windows 7.

In my old MSDN library (for Visual Studio 2008) documentation, I come across an article about threading in C#. I try to convert to C++/CLI. I have encountered many problems in converting. Now there is only one left: `C3371: Cannot take the address of 'Producer::ThreadRun' unless creating delegate instance`.

Title of the original doc: *How to: Synchronize a Producer and a Consumer Thread (C# Programming Guide)*

I cannot find the original document in online MSDN library. It seems like it has been deleted. Nor I cannot find it anywhere on the web.

In the document, the code has:

- A producer thread that keeps 20 integers in the queue
- A consumer thread that works on the number just input in the queue
- A main thread will display number in queue every 2.5 seconds. As the main thread works on the queue, other threads are stopped.

Well, here is the original code in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SyncEvents
{
    public SyncEvents()
    {

        _newItemEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _exitThreadEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        _eventArray = new WaitHandle[2];
        _eventArray[0] = _newItemEvent;
        _eventArray[1] = _exitThreadEvent;
    }

    public EventWaitHandle ExitThreadEvent
    {
        get { return _exitThreadEvent; }
    }
    public EventWaitHandle NewItemEvent
    {
        get { return _newItemEvent; }
    }
    public WaitHandle[] EventArray
    {
        get { return _eventArray; }
    }

    private EventWaitHandle _newItemEvent;
    private EventWaitHandle _exitThreadEvent;
    private WaitHandle[] _eventArray;
}
public class Producer
{
    public Producer(Queue<int> q, SyncEvents e)
    {
        _queue = q;
        _syncEvents = e;
    }
    // Producer.ThreadRun
    public void ThreadRun()
    {
        int count = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        while (!_syncEvents.ExitThreadEvent.WaitOne(0, false))
        {
            lock (((ICollection)_queue).SyncRoot)
            {
                while (_queue.Count < 20)
                {
                    _queue.Enqueue(r.Next(0, 100));
                    _syncEvents.NewItemEvent.Set();
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Producer thread: produced {0} items", count);
    }
    private Queue<int> _queue;
    private SyncEvents _syncEvents;
}

public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer(Queue<int> q, SyncEvents e)
    {
        _queue = q;
        _syncEvents = e;
    }
    // Consumer.ThreadRun
    public void ThreadRun()
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (WaitHandle.WaitAny(_syncEvents.EventArray) != 1)
        {
            lock (((ICollection)_queue).SyncRoot)
            {
                int item = _queue.Dequeue();
            }
            count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Consumer Thread: consumed {0} items", count);
    }
    private Queue<int> _queue;
    private SyncEvents _syncEvents;
}

public class ThreadSyncSample
{
    private static void ShowQueueContents(Queue<int> q)
    {
        lock (((ICollection)q).SyncRoot)
        {
            foreach (int item in q)
            {
                Console.Write("{0, 2} ", item);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();
        SyncEvents syncEvents = new SyncEvents();

        Console.WriteLine("Configuring worker threads...");
        Producer producer = new Producer(queue, syncEvents);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(queue, syncEvents);
        Thread producerThread = new Thread(producer.ThreadRun);
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(consumer.ThreadRun);

        Console.WriteLine("Launching producer and consumer threads...");
        producerThread.Start();
        consumerThread.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2500);
            ShowQueueContents(queue);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Signaling threads to terminate...");
        syncEvents.ExitThreadEvent.Set();

        producerThread.Join();
        consumerThread.Join();
    }
}
```

I have converted to the following C++/CLI. Please note that

- There is no getter as I find out if I have getter I cannot get the WaitOne function in `Producer::ThreadRun`
- Instead of `lock` in C#, I use `Monitor::Enter` and `Monitor::Exit`
- Compilation error in `main()` when creating a thread at `gcnew Thread(&Producer::ThreadRun)`
- Error: C3374: Cannot take the address of `Producer::ThreadRun` unless creating delegate instance.

code in C++/CLI:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

public ref class SyncEvents
{
public:
    property System::Threading::EventWaitHandle ^ _newItemEvent;
    property System::Threading::EventWaitHandle ^ _exitThreadEvent;
    property array<System::Threading::WaitHandle ^> ^ _eventArray;

public:
    SyncEvents()
    {
        _newItemEvent = gcnew System::Threading::AutoResetEvent(false);
        _exitThreadEvent = gcnew System::Threading::ManualResetEvent(false);

        _eventArray = gcnew array<System::Threading::WaitHandle ^>(2);
        _eventArray[0] = _newItemEvent;
        _eventArray[1] = _exitThreadEvent;
    }

};

public ref class Producer
{
private:
    System::Collections::Generic::Queue<int> ^ _queue;
    SyncEvents ^ _syncEvents;

public:
    Producer(System::Collections::Generic::Queue<int> ^ q, SyncEvents ^ e)
    {
        _queue = q;
        _syncEvents = e;
    }
    void ThreadRun()
    {
        int count = 0;
        Random ^ r = gcnew Random();

        while (!_syncEvents->_exitThreadEvent->WaitOne(0, false))
        {
            Monitor::Enter(((System::Collections::ICollection ^)_queue)->SyncRoot);
            try
            {
                while (_queue->Count < 20)
                {
                    _queue->Enqueue(r->Next(0, 100));
                    _syncEvents->_newItemEvent->Set();
                    count++;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor::Exit(((System::Collections::ICollection ^)_queue)->SyncRoot);
            }
        }
        Console::WriteLine("Producer thread: produced {0} items", count);
    }
};

public ref class Consumer
{
private:
    System::Collections::Generic::Queue<int> ^ _queue;
    SyncEvents ^ _syncEvents;

public:
    Consumer(System::Collections::Generic::Queue<int> ^ q, SyncEvents ^ e)
    {
        _queue = q;
        _syncEvents = e;
    }
    void ThreadRun()
    {
        int count = 0;

        while (System::Threading::WaitHandle::WaitAny(_syncEvents->_eventArray) != 1)
        {
            Monitor::Enter(((System::Collections::ICollection ^)_queue)->SyncRoot);
            try
            {
                int item = _queue->Dequeue();
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor::Exit(((System::Collections::ICollection ^)_queue)->SyncRoot);
            }
            count++;
        }
        Console::WriteLine("Consumer Thread: consumed {0} items", count);
    }
};

static void ShowQueueContents(System::Collections::Generic::Queue<int> ^ _q)
{
    Monitor::Enter(((System::Collections::ICollection ^)_q)->SyncRoot);
    try
    {
        for each (int item in _q)
            Console::WriteLine("{0, 3} ", item);
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor::Exit(((System::Collections::ICollection ^)_q)->SyncRoot);
    }
};

int main()
{
    System::Collections::Generic::Queue<int> ^ queue 
        = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::Queue<int>(); 
    SyncEvents ^ syncEvents = gcnew SyncEvents();

    Console::WriteLine("Configuring worker threads...");
    Producer ^ producer = gcnew Producer(queue, syncEvents);
    Consumer ^ consumer = gcnew Consumer(queue, syncEvents);
    System::Threading::Thread ^ producerThread = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(&Producer::ThreadRun);
    System::Threading::Thread ^ consumerThread = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(&Consumer::ThreadRun);

    Console::WriteLine("Launching producer and cosumer threads...");
    producerThread->Start();
    consumerThread->Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Thread::Sleep(2500);
        ShoqQueueuContents(queue);
    }

    Console::WriteLine("Signaling threads to terminate...");        
    syncEvents->_exitThreadEvent->Set();

    producerThread->Join();
    consumerThread->Join();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use something like ConcurrentQueue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 System::Threading::Thread ^ producerThread = 
      gcnew System::Threading::Thread(&Producer::ThreadRun);
```

The Thread class constructor requires a *delegate object*.  You are used to the C# language syntax sugar that automagically converts a method to a delegate.  But that sugar doesn't exist in C++/CLI, you have to create the delegate object yourself.  And be explicit both about the target object and the target method, the C# compiler wants to infer the target object.  This does give the C++/CLI language some capabilities that C# doesn't have, at the cost of having to write beefier code:

```
 System::Threading::Thread ^ producerThread = 
      gcnew System::Threading::Thread(
          gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(producer, &Producer::ThreadRun)
      );
```

Do consider the existing support in .NET 4 for these scenarios, like BlockingCollection<> and ConcurrentQueue<>.

Comment: Ah that works. Thanks. I like C# because it does many things for me. In C++/CLI, I have to type many more things. For example, when converting the `lock (((ICollection)_queue).SyncRoot)` to C++/CLI, I have to be careful about which `ICollection` in the original code means.